# react styling web page with map function

Tags: reactjs

Would it be possible for someone to tell me how to put as many folders (icons) and text as possible below each folder in a row.
At the moment the one folders and text are displayed are displayed on each row. I would like to be able to display 5 folders all on the same row.
Thanks.

```
render() {
    return (<div>
        {this.state.Folder.map((item, index) => {
            return (<div >
                <FontAwesome name={"fas fa-folder fa-3x"} />
                <h2> {item.FolderName}</h2>
            </div>
            );
        })}
    </div>)
```

Comment: Could you maybe explain what exactly you want to achieve in greater detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the wrapper div you could add style/class to display grid, then set the column number to be 5.

Here's an example for the class:

```
.wrapper { 
    display: grid; 
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr); 
    grid-gap: 10px; 
}
```

More details at MDN [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout).